# Django: Insert or update database entries

Tags: python, django

I created the following function where I either create a new database entry or update it if `event_pk` already exists. Now I looked into `update_or_create`. However, that doesn't work in my case, as the other entries (yhat, etc.) always differ. Do you have any better idea to write it so I don't repeat myself as I do now? One more idea I had was that I could maybe save `event=event_obj, yhat=event_forecast.get('yhat')` etc. in a `dict` and unpack it. But didn't figure out how that could work.

```
def insert_forecast_data_to_db(self) -> None:
    """Insert or update forecast data in database."""
    forecast_data = self.get_forecast_data()
    for event_pk, event_forecast in forecast_data.items():
        event_obj = Event.objects.get(pk=event)
        forecast_obj = Forecast.objects.filter(event=event_pk)
        if forecast_obj.exists():
            forecast_obj.update(
                event=event_obj,
                yhat=event_forecast.get('yhat'),
                yhat_lower=event_forecast.get('yhat_lower'),
                yhat_upper=event_forecast.get('yhat_upper'),
                img_key=event_forecast.get('img_key'),
            )
        else:
            Forecast.objects.create(
                event=event_obj,
                yhat=event_forecast.get('yhat'),
                yhat_lower=event_forecast.get('yhat_lower'),
                yhat_upper=event_forecast.get('yhat_upper'),
                img_key=event_forecast.get('img_key'),
            )
```

Comment: Use `get_or_create` and then `update()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I just figured it out. That's what I was aiming for:

```
def insert_forecast_data_to_db(self) -> None:
    """Insert or update forecast data in database."""
    forecast_data = self.get_forecast_data()
    for event_pk, event_forecast in forecast_data.items():
        event_obj = Event.objects.get(pk=event_pk)
        data = {
            'event': event_obj,
            'yhat': event_forecast.get('yhat'),
            'yhat_lower': event_forecast.get('yhat_lower'),
            'yhat_upper': event_forecast.get('yhat_upper'),
            'img_key': event_forecast.get('img_key'),
        }

        forecast_obj = Forecast.objects.filter(event=event_pk)
        forecast_obj.update(
            **data
        ) if forecast_obj.exists() else Forecast.objects.create(**data)
```